# Cannot convert Systems.Collections.GenericList<T> to T

Tags: c#, .net

I have dictionary with value being a list.  I need to read each of the list's to extract a field.  But getting the following error at the foreach loop

> cannot convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery.Employee>` to
>   `UserQuery.Employee`

It works if I use the firstorDefault as in the commented line for var iValue. But I will have multiple records to check in the dictionary that I am reading(though in this example, I hard coded 1, to test my code).

```
void Main()
{
    var svalue =1;
    List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>()
    {
         new Employee{ EID=10, Ename="John"},
         new Employee{ EID=11, Ename="Adam"},
         new Employee{ EID=12, Ename="Ram"}
    };
    List<Employee> emplist1 = new List<Employee>()
    {
         new Employee{ EID=1, Ename="Jo"},
         new Employee{ EID=1, Ename="Ad"},
         new Employee{ EID=1, Ename="Ra"}
    };

    var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
    dict1.Add(1, emplist);
    dict1.Add(2, emplist1);

    //var ivalue = dict1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == svalue).Value.ToList();
    var ivalue = dict1.Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)).Select(x => x.Value);

    Console.WriteLine(ivalue);
    foreach (Employee emp in ivalue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emp.EID);
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public int EID { get; set;}
    public string Ename {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Where receives two times the KeyValuePair and of course returns true for both KeyValuePair because you ask always the same question. Does the dictionary contains the Key == 1? Yes. So the return from the Where is an enumerable of two `List<Employee>` elements that cannot be converted to a single generic list.

```
var ivalue = dict1.FirstOrDefault(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1));
if(ivalue.Value != null)
    foreach (Employee emp in ivalue.Value)
       Console.WriteLine(emp.EID);
```

Of course, as pointed in comments, this use of Linq is unwarranted because your code could simplified with just

```
List<Employee> empList;
// Try directly to get the List<Employee> that match the Key
// if found you have the empList initialized with the matching list
// otherwise TryGetValue returns false.
if(dict.TryGetValue(1, out empList))
    foreach (Employee emp in empList)
       Console.WriteLine(emp.EID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code

```
 var ivalue = dict1
   .Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)) //TODO: Very strange condition: check it
   .Select(x => x.Value);
```

returns `IEnumerable<List<Employee>>` as a result (`ivalue`). Since you want `IEnumerable<Employee>` only, you have to *flatten* the result:

```
 var ivalue = dict1
   .Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1))
   .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value); // kvp: we still have key-value pair
```

However, it's not the way we deal with dictionaries; you're, probably, looking for something like this (let's preserve some Linq: - `.Select(emp => emp.EID)`):

```
 if (dict1.TryGetValue(1, out var ivalue)) // do we have corresponding value?
   Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ivalue // if yes, print them out
     .Select(emp => emp.EID)));
```

Comment: I still don't understand why so many (5 already) answers suggest to use a Linq query that makes no sense. This is much slower than a simpler `if (dict1.ContainsKey(1))` and harder to read as well

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto: I've tried to answer the question put in the header: why compile time error "cannot convert type..." *appeared*, and how the current code can be *amended* (the trick is in `SelectMany` instead of `Select`). As for the implementation I agree with you that, *Linq* is not the best solution in the context.

Comment: Thank you CamiloTerevinto and Dmitry Bychenko. appreciate your help. I have adopted the TryGetValue and I have the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you normally work with a Dictionary. What you want to do is something like this:

```
if (dict1.ContainsKey(1)) // if the dictionary contains the key
{
    var ivalue = dict1[1]; // get the value of that key
}
```

With this, you are using the most effective way to search the dictionary. So you should do this instead:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
dict1.Add(1, emplist);
dict1.Add(2, emplist1);

if (dict1.ContainsKey(1))
{
    var ivalue = dict1[1];

    Console.WriteLine(ivalue); // this will print System.Collections.Generic.List<Employee>
    foreach (Employee emp in ivalue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emp.EID);
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `TryGetValue`:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
dict1.Add(1, emplist);
dict1.Add(2, emplist1);
List<Employee> ivalue = null;
if (dict1.TryGetValue(1, out ivalue))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ivalue); // this will print System.Collections.Generic.List<Employee>
    foreach (Employee emp in ivalue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(emp.EID);
    }
}
```

Comment: This the way we *should have implemented* the routine (if you let me add my 5 cents, I suggest using `dict1.TryGetValue(1, out var ivalue` in the code)` syntax; `Console.WriteLine(ivalue);` is dubious since `ivalue` is `List<T>`). However, i may be the cause of the compile time error - "cannot convert type ... to UserQuery.Employee" - that is the question.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I don't normally use c# 6/7 syntax unless the OP already did or mention that they are using VS2015/2017, but I'd have used it. `Console.WriteLine` accepts `object` and does a `.ToString()` on it

Comment: Thank you for the comment: `"this will print System.Collections.Generic.List<Employee>"` is the very thing I meant by dubious code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var ivalue = dict1.Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)).Select(x => x.Value);` You're filtering your list with the `Where` method and then selecting all the values with `Select`.

It's normal that you get that exception, because Select gives you a list, not a single entry. You should either `foreach` that list, or use `FirstOrDefault` and get 1 single value.

```
foreach (var value in dict1.Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)).Select(x => x.Value))
{
    // ...
}
```

Or

`var ivalue = dict1.Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var ivalue = dict1.Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)).Select(x => x.Value);
```

will return an 'IEnumerable' with elements of type List.
so you would need two nested foreach loops:

the 'outer' one to iterate through all the lists retrieved from the Dictionary, the 'inner' one to iterate through all the employees in the current List.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've meant : `dict1.ContainsKey(1))`

I think you're after this :

```
var ivalue = dict1.FirstOrDefault(d =>d.Key==1 ).Value ;


if (ivalue!=null)
foreach (Employee emp in ivalue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(emp.EID);
}
```

Notice that this :

```
var ivalue = dict1.Where(kvp => dict1.ContainsKey(1)).Select(x => x.Value);
```

checks if dictionary has 1 as key , but *doesn't consider* that key in results.